# Is there a way to find where a line code is executed?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, database-migration

I'm using `python 3.5` and downloaded an updated version of my project from `bitbucket`.

When I try to `makemigrations` I get:

```
django.core.exceptions.FieldDoesNotExist: users.user has no field named 'surname'
```

Is there a way to find where this is executed? Because in my `models.py` I have `users.lastname`.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grep for the .surname field

In Linux just open a terminal at your root dir of the project, and type `grep -irn .surname`

The i is "Case Insensitive"
The r is "Recursive"
and the n is "Line Number"

This will tell you the file and where in the file the issue is.

if you don't have linux, and you don't bave bash for windows on your machine, then it's well worth downloading cygwin, and you can issue the same command as above to search for the call to .surname